# Android ListView: out of memory exception

Tags: android, android-listview, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I am reading some images from SD card and showing them in a list view here is the code from Custom List Adapter

```
  File imgFile = new  File(act.getimage());
  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
  holder.picView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

but while loading this listView i get `outOfMemory Exception`. is this because of size of images ? 
*Here is the LogCat*

```
04-04 14:49:37.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 14:49:37.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18934): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-04 14:49:37.372: E/AndroidRuntime(18934):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did u increase the memory of your emulator?

Comment: have you googled about your question..there are lot of answers..check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview?rq=1

Comment: i am not using Emulator, i am using Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: Yes, Image sizes used in listview eats up all app memory. Solution is to keep the image size reasonable, Re-size them accordingly and re-use the views, Also keep bitmap/drawable free while image is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this function to decode image from sdcard path**

```
public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

**How to use?**

```
holder.picView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(act.getimage()));
```

**Note:**

you can change REQUIRED_SIZE value as per your need.

Comment: thank you, it worked. I was not sure of the reason of error that's why i asked this question, and your answer worked like a charm.

Comment: glad to know that works for you

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty common error. You are using a big image for each list element instead of use a small thumb...

I use a lib called [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to deal with images, check it out.

Check this example.

```
Picasso.with(YOUR_CONTEXT).load(new File(YOUR_PATH)).fit().centerCrop().into(YOUR_VIEW);
```

Answer (score 0):

use android-query to display images in listview.

you can find tutorial of android-query [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/)

i hope it helps.